# How to suppress insertion of letter labels after year for references from the same year

Tags: bibtex, natbib, apa-style

I hope this is a simple question, but I've been googling it all evening and haven't made much progress.  I am currently working on converting my CV to LaTeX (which is going quite well), but I've come across one hurdle: I have many BibTeX entries from the same year.  In a typical paper, these references should be given individual identifiers (e.g. Author, 1990a; Author, 1990b; and so on), however, in a CV, this looks a little silly.

Does anyone know how I can disable the automatic lettering of references from the same year?

I am using natbib and bibentry and the apalike bibliography style

Preamble:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[NoDate,LabelsAligned]{currvita}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes, natbib, bibentry, anysize, titlesec}
\usepackage[hmargin=1in,vmargin=1in]{geometry}
\pagestyle{headings}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{10pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\newcommand{\bibverse}[1]{\begin{verse} \bibentry{#1}. \end{verse}}
```

Document:

```
\begin{document}
 \nobibliography*
 \begin{cv}{}
 \subsection*{Publications}
 \bibverse{Author2012}
 \bibverse{Author2012a}
 \end{cv}
 \bibliographystyle{apalike}
 \nobibliography{ReferenceDesk}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Find the file `apalike.bst` in your TeX distribution (likely in a spot such as `.../bibtex/bst/apalike`, where `...` is a root directory of the TeX distribution), make a copy of it and name the copy, say, `my-apalike.bst`. Open the new file in an editor of your choice and search for the function `FUNCTION {output.year.check}` (probably starting around line 120 of the file). In this function, locate the line:

```
    " (" year * extra.label * ")" *
```

Remove the substring `extra.label *`. I.e., the line should now read as follows:

```
      " (" year * ")" *
```

Save the file (either to your current working directory or in some directory that's searched by TeX's filename database operations, and update the TeX filename database if necessary) and be sure to use the instruction

```
\bibliographystyle{my-apalike}
```

from now on.

Comment: Is it also possible to add a similar command to the *.tex file so that one doesnt need to edit the bst file? Something like: \DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps... ?

Comment: @Mil - I'm afraid that in the case of the `apalike` style file, it's not possible to bypass editing the style file.

Comment: Ah, yes I see, you are right! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternate answer for those using **biblatex** with **format=apa** instead of **natlib**.

1- Locate the file apa.cbx (likely in tex\latex\biblatex-apa folder),

2 -Get to the line (more or less 22) where we see

```
   \DeclareFieldFormat{extradate}{\iffieldnums{labelyear}{\mknumalph{#1}}{\apashortdash\mknumalph{#1}}}
```

The command **\mknumalph{#1}** 's role is to display the label year postfix. Erase it and it won't be shown anymore. It would then look like

```
   \DeclareFieldFormat{extradate}{\iffieldnums{labelyear}{}{\apashortdash\mknumalph{#1}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put curly braces to year. For example, in the bib entry,

```
year={{1990}}
```

This worked in my case.