# agsm bibliography style - suppress insertion of letter labels after year for entries with same year

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

Very similarly to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58452/how-to-suppress-insertion-of-letter-labels-after-year-for-references-from-the-sa), how do you stop letter labels being inserted after the years in citations of references with the same year (and author(s)) when using the **agsm** bibliography style? What changes need to be made to **agsm.bst**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you proceed as follows:

- Find the file `agsm.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file and call the copy (say) `agsm-noextrayearlabels.bst`. Do not modify an original, unrenamed file from the TeX distribution.
- Open `agsm-noextrayearlabels.bst` in your favorite text editor; the program you use to edit your tex files will do fine.
- Go to line 1301 in the file, where you should find the line

  ```
  ITERATE {forward.pass}
  ```

  Comment out this line -- or delete it.
- Save the file `agsm-noextrayearlabels.bst` either in the directory where your main tex file is located or in a local directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter option, be sure to also update the filename database of your TeX ditribution.
- In your main tex file, change the instruction

  ```
  \bibligraphystyle{agsm}
  ```

  to

  ```
  \bibliographystyle{agsm-noextrayearlabels}
  ```
- Rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes.

Happy BibTeXing!